# Save XML File in Project Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, entity-framework

```
try
{
    XElement contactsFromFile = XElement.Load("App_Data/EmployeeFinList.xml");
    var xEle = new XElement("Employees",
        from emp in ListFromBasicPay
        select new XElement("Employee",
            new XAttribute("EmpID", emp.employee_personal_id),
            new XElement("GrandTotal", emp.grandTotal),
            new XElement("Housing", emp.housing),
            new XElement("BasePay", emp.base_pay),
            new XElement("XchangeRate", emp.Exchange_rate)));

    xEle.Save("..\\changesetDB.xml");

    Debug.WriteLine("Converted to XML");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

I want to save the xml file in a folder i created in my project. I will then use that xml file created in my folder and read and write from it. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Do you want to add it to you solution directories under your project????

Comment: Yes! I have two projects in my solution, one for the UIs and the other  containing my linq to entities clasess . i want to save it in my solution directory

Comment: what is the exact path where you want to save this `xEle.Save("..\\changesetDB.xml");` normally you should be able to do the following
`xEle.Save("changesetDB.xml");` but you should capture the Path of where you are trying to save this file

Comment: i was just playing around with that, if i use xEle.Save("changesetDB.xml"); .. are you saying that will work? how do i capture the path?

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll .. i get this error when i use  xEle.Save("changesetDB.xml")

Comment: `string path = Application.ExecutablePath;` or `string path = Application.StartupPath;` or `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Comment: im new to this.. what do i do with this? string path = Application.StartupPath;etc

Comment: @DineshPersaud let me get this straight.. You want to save that xml file and at the same time add it as an item to your project so it will show in your solution explorer in VS??????? Like simulating the "add existing item" of Visual Studio????!!!!!

Comment: @RedSerpent I want to save it.. so when i deploy this web application, i can read/write to it, i dont want it to show up in my vs application.

Comment: You need to get the application's running path or the location of where you are deploying the application..

Comment: string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

               xEle.Save(path+"changesetDB.xml");

Answer (score 5):

Use    `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`
 To get the full path of you assembly, Combine that with `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()`.

That would be like:

```
String path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

xEle.Save(path + @"\myfilename.xml");
```

Though you should note that if your application is installed in C:\Program Files for example, you'll need some sort of elevation permissions to be able to write there depending on the security settings of the machine your app has been deployed on. It is best to always have a work directory in some other location like (Application Data) for example..

Answer (score -1):

Use Red Serpent's answer for getting your project's folder:

```
  String path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName
  (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Then use:

```
   string mySavePath = Path.Combine(path, myFolder);

   string myXMLPath = Path.Combine(SavePath,"changesetDB.xml");
```

You can then use **myXMLPath** to read and write from XML file you just created.

Comment: what is myFolder?? what is SavePath??